# How insert a circle with a number in it within the window coordinate?

Tags: python, matplotlib, geometry

I would like to make this kind of figure :

[image]

But I don't know how I can create the circle with a text in it.
I would like the circle to be place according to the window instead of the axis. All example I found place the circle according to coordinate of the axis but I would like to have a coordinate base on the window. like at 0.2 for X direction and 0.9 for Y direction
For now I have this code :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


t=np.arange(0,10,0.01)
y1=np.sin(2*3.14*10*t)

plt.figure(1)
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.01)
plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(t,y1)

# create the circle with black border and grey fill, and the text 1 in it
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is as easy as creating a circle and creating a text. Both actions are well documented and there are enough questions about that. Alternatively one may also create a single annotation with a circular box around it. That is also shown in many places. So what exact problem do you face here?

Comment: My issue is each I don't want the circle to be added to the subplot but to the window.

Comment: Where is the difference between adding the circle to the subplots and adding it to "the window"? Make sure the question contains the actual problem description.

Comment: Ok, I edited the post.

Comment: See what I mean: Even though you stated the task to have the encircled number in terms of the window, you still get answers showing you stuff that you probably already know how to do. That's why it is important to clearly state **the problem** in a question (i.e. what hinders you obtaining the desired result.)

Comment: Yes you're right. Always tough for me to write clear questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three out of many options to create an annotation or text **in figure coordinates**:

- Specify the `xycoords` argument of [`annotate`](https://matplotlib.org/users/annotations.html#basic-annotation):

  ```
  plt.annotate("1",(0.2,0.9), xycoords="figure fraction",
               bbox={"boxstyle" : "circle", "color":"grey"})
  ```
- Use [`figtext`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.figtext.html) to create your text.

  ```
  plt.figtext(0.2,0.9,"1",
              bbox={"boxstyle" : "circle", "color":"grey"})
  ```
- Specify the transform to use for the usual [`text`](https://matplotlib.org/api/text_api.html#matplotlib.text.Text):

  ```
  plt.text(0.2,0.9,"1", transform=plt.gcf().transFigure,
           bbox={"boxstyle" : "circle", "color":"grey"})
  ```

Comment: They are all equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

You can use plt.text

```
plt.text(0.6, 0.5, "test", size=10,
         ha="center", va="center",
         bbox=dict(boxstyle="circle")
         )
```

Comment: This won't work because if I move the plot (drag the curve) the text move also.

Comment: So do it on the figure `a = plt.figure(1); a.text(...`

Answer (score 0):

You can use patches -

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches
import numpy as np


t=np.arange(0,10,0.01)
y1=np.sin(2*3.14*10*t)


fig1 = plt.figure(figsize = (18,18))
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')
ax1.add_patch(
    patches.Circle(
        (0, 0.5),   # (x,y)
        0.2           # width
    )
)
tx = plt.text(-0.07, 0.44, "1", fontsize=18, color='white')

ax1.plot(t,y1)

plt.show()
```

Comment: This won't work because if I move the plot (drag the curve) the text move also.