# Plot multiple circles with numbers in them in Python with loop (blank figure returned)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49572934/how-insert-a-circle-with-a-number-in-it-within-the-window-coordinate) question but for many circles with numbers in them. I don't know why but the figure that is generated comes out blank. I would like a figure with 9 circles (having 1 of 3 colors), with the "job_id" printed in the circle.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

d = {'job_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
     'hub': ['ZH1', 'ZH1', 'ZH1', 'ZH2', 'ZH2', 'ZH3', 'ZH3', 'ZH3', 'ZH3'], 
     'alerts': [18, 35, 45, 8, 22, 34, 29, 20, 30],
    'color': ['orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'green', 'green', 'lightblue', 'lightblue', 'lightblue', 'lightblue']}

df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)

ax=plt.subplot(111)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row)
    ax.text(index,row['alerts'],str(row['job_id']), transform=plt.gcf().transFigure,
         bbox={"boxstyle" : "circle", "color":row['color']})

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two problems.

- The transform is set to the figure transform. This would take numbers between 0 and 1 in both directions. However your data ranges much above 1. Since it seems you want to show the circles in data coordinates anyways, remove the `transform=...` part.
- Text elements cannot be used to autoscale the axes. You would hence need to set the limits manually.

Complete code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

d = {'job_id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 
     'hub': ['ZH1', 'ZH1', 'ZH1', 'ZH2', 'ZH2', 'ZH3', 'ZH3', 'ZH3', 'ZH3'], 
     'alerts': [18, 35, 45, 8, 22, 34, 29, 20, 30],
    'color': ['orange', 'orange', 'orange', 'green', 'green', 'lightblue', 'lightblue', 'lightblue', 'lightblue']}

df=pd.DataFrame(data=d)

ax=plt.subplot(111)
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    ax.text(index, row['alerts'],str(row['job_id']),
         bbox={"boxstyle" : "circle", "color":row['color']})

ax.set(xlim=(-1,len(df)), ylim=(df["alerts"].min()-5, df["alerts"].max()+5))
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If one of the circles has a 2 digit number in it, the size of the circle increases. Do you know how to fix the circle size?

Comment: You would need to separate the the circles from the text then. Meaning you use a text without `bbox`, and create a scatter plot in the background.

Answer (score 1):

You need to map the x-y coordinates within 0-1 range. To do so I divide the x and y by the maximum value in the DataFrame. Later, I adjust the x- and y-limits accordingly and label the axes to display the actual values.

You also had only two `'green'` but four `'lightblue'` in your dictionary. I corrected it. I also replaced `index` bby `row['job_id']` because index starts with 0 but you would want to plot the circle 1 at `x=1`

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    ax.text(row['job_id']/max(d['job_id']),row['alerts']/max(d['alerts']),str(row['job_id']), 
            bbox={"boxstyle" : "circle", "color":row['color']})

plt.xlim(0, 1.1)    
plt.ylim(0, 1.1) 
plt.xticks(np.linspace(0,1,10), range(10))
plt.yticks(np.linspace(0,1,10), range(0,50,5))
```

[image]